# Android Device Admin app enabled by default

Tags: android, admin, device-admin

I have a question about admin apps on Android that I can't find the answer to. I followed the guide on creating an admin app from here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#java

I successfully created an admin app but there's something that's confusing me. I have a fresh device (Moto G6) and when I go into Settings->Security&Location->DeviceAdminApps I see a list of admin apps on the device. Right now it lists my app and a Google Play Services app titled "Find My Device". The only difference, though, is that the google app was on by default. Normally, and including in my app, when I try to use an admin feature (through DevicePolicyManager), an android page pops up asking me to enable it as an admin app. Since the Google app is already enabled, that pop up doesn't need to appear.

So, my question is how do I make an app an admin app by default (without needing the pop up page)? I assume something needs to be done on boot up but I have no idea what that Google app does. Does anyone out there have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my question is how do I make an app an admin app by default (without needing the pop up page)?

Build your own firmware with your own custom build of Android, where you pre-install your device admin app and set things up for it to be pre-enabled.

Alternatively, I think if you create a device owner app, it will be enabled upon installation, but that installation happens when the device is being first set up.

Ordinary device admin apps require users to agree to enable them, for blindingly obvious security reasons.